# How to Access the Vue instance in the Script Tag Before the Export default, Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I would like to to access some properties from a plugin which was registered on my vue instance in the script tag, just before the export[image: vscode screenshot]

Obviously i can't use the `this` keyword to refer to my vue instance from there, so how can I access the current vue instance?

Answer (score 0):

`it is not a best practice`, but you can access the nuxt (so also the vue instance) with the

```
window.$nuxt
```

here you have everything you need, but **you have to consider that if you're using nuxt in an SSR context, this does not work**, since you cannot use the window object.

Comment: Ok thanks, i think i will transfer the code to the created lifecycle hook since i need effective SSR